# How To Include An Optional Null Parameter In SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures

I would like to create a stored proc that has an optional parameter in the WHERE part of the proc. My C# code can pass in null or a valid product id for this proc. Here it is:

```
declare @ProductID int
set @ProductID = null

select
    *
from
    Products
where   
    Name like '%Hasbro%'
    if @ProductID is not null
        begin
            and ProductID = @ProductID
        end
```

This code doesn't work. If the product id is null, I want it to only look for products with the name 'Hasbro' in it. If the product id is not null, I want it to look for products with the name 'Hasbro' in it and for matching product ids.

Thanks!

UPDATE:

Here is the working code. Thank you everyone for helping me get this!

```
declare @ProductID int
set @ProductID = null

select
    *
from
    Products
where
    Name like '%Hasbro%'
    and (( @ProductID is null ) or ( @ProductID is not null and ProductID = @ProductID ))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work also...

```
select
    *
from
    Products
where
    Name like '%Hasbro%' and
    (
      ( @ProductID is null ) or
      ( @ProductID is not null and ProductID = @ProductID ) 
    )
```

Comment: This can be simplified to: (@ProductId Is NULL or ProductId = @ProductId)

Answer (score 2):

A simpler way would be to use `ISNULL`

```
where
    Name like '%Hasbro%'
    and ProductID = ISNULL(@ProductID, ProductID)
```

This way, if `@ProductID` is omitted (ie, it's `NULL` in the stored procedure call), then you fall back on the original value and essentially it degrades to `WHERE Name like '%Hasbro%' and ProductID = ProductID` - the second part of that is always going to be true.

Though according to the code you've got posted, it's not a stored procedure at all right now.  Just so you know, you don't `DECLARE` parameters like that in SQL Server, your stored procedure declaration would look like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[YourStoredProcName]
    @ProductID = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    -- stuff goes here
END
```

And then if the stored procedure is called as just `EXEC YourStoredProcName`, then `@ProductID` will be `NULL` and that `ISNULL()` call will work a treat.

---

**edit**:  except this won't work for a nullable column, which in this case apparently it is.  For any non-nullable column, this is probably the simplest solution.

Comment: When I run this the results are very small compared to the total number of rows in the table. The table only has a handful of null product ids. When I run select * from products wher productid is not null I get over 1300 rows.

Comment: Are you also filtering with `Name like '%Hasbro%'` ?