# Comparing same column to two possible parameters tsql.

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Here is my scenario the user can select 2 possible parameters ( @param1, @param2).
 If the user selects param1 then the WHERE clause uses the first one. If the user selects param1 and param2 then they are both used in the WHERE clause.

If I had access to the DOM I could use some c# logic based on the controls. In this case I cannot do that so it needs to be pure t-sql. HERE IS SOME PSUEDOCODE for what I need to accomplish:

```
// NOT REAL CODE 
 IF param1 is selected and param2 is not then use param1 
 IF param1 and param2 are selected use both (I can do this part with an IN statement)
```

How can I accomplish this using pure tsql?

Comment: What determines if a parameter is selected? Do you pass a special value for `@param2` or something?

Comment: param1 comes from a ddl on the page. it will be passed the most often, the second will only be used once in a while by the user for a specific purpose.

Comment: Your mention of `IN` implies an `OR` relationship, i.e. something like `where Col = @param1 or ( Col = @param2 or @param2 is NULL )`.

Comment: IN may not be the best choice then. it needs to be AND. Forgive me the data person is out this week and I have to get this done. So I am struggling with the SQL!!

Comment: You mean `where Col = @param1 and ( Col = @param2 or @param2 is NULL or @param2 = '' or @param2 = 'n/a' )`?  Are there any more unspecified or magic values in answer to Dark Falcon's comment?

Comment: If param2 is null then use param1. If param2 is not null then use param1 and param2.

Comment: Then we're down to `where Col = @param1 and ( Col = @param2 or @param2 is NULL )`.

Comment: I joined the table to itself and then compared the both parameters to it. Found a trick and it worked. Thank you for the replies.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is like what you are looking to do: [How To Include An Optional Null Parameter In SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6512996/how-to-include-an-optional-null-parameter-in-sql-server)

You could do something like this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM myTable
  WHERE
    (@param2 IS NULL AND myCol = @param1) OR
    (@param2 IS NOT NULL AND myCol IN (@param1, @param2))
```